# Install Anywhere unsuccesfull scenario

Tags: installation, installanywhere

In InstallAnywhere project, how it detects that installation is unsuccessful. It does not seem to see the log file for it. Does it check if the exception has occured anywhere then it will fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variable named, `$INSTALL_SUCCESS$`. If the installation is successful, then you can get some value from this variable.